# java.lang.AssertionError: could not bind to KeyChainService

Tags: android, android-asynctask, certificado

estoy intentando hacer uso de certificado digital en Android para logarme en un Webview. En todos los dispositivos que he usado no encuentro problema pero en los Huawei me salta esta excepción:

**java.lang.AssertionError: could not bind to KeyChainService**

¿A alguién le suena?

Gracias.

API 24 (Android 7.0) EMUI 5.1, Código:

```
@SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    override fun onReceivedClientCertRequest(view: WebView, request: ClientCertRequest) {
        var keyTypes: Array<String>? = request.keyTypes
        if (keyTypes == null)
            keyTypes = arrayOf()

        KeyChain.choosePrivateKeyAlias(
                this@LoginClaveActivity,
                KeyChainAliasCallback { alias ->
                    if (alias == null) {
                        request.cancel()
                        return@KeyChainAliasCallback
                    }
                    object : AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void): Void? {
                            val privateKey: PrivateKey?
                            val certificateChain: Array<X509Certificate>?
                            try {
                                privateKey = KeyChain.getPrivateKey(this@LoginClaveActivity, alias)
                                certificateChain = KeyChain.getCertificateChain(this@LoginClaveActivity, alias)
                            } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
                                request.ignore()
                                return null
                            } catch (e: KeyChainException) {
                                request.ignore()
                                return null
                            }

                            request.proceed(privateKey, certificateChain)
                            return null
                        }
                    }.execute()
                },
                keyTypes,
                request.principals,
                request.host,
                request.port, null)
    }
```

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Android llevan los que te dan error? ¿Puedes poner algo de código en el que se vea cómo intentas conectar con el servicio de certificados?

Comment: API 25 y el codigo que he puesto va dentro de una clase propia que extiende de WebClient.

Comment: Concretamente el error lo da en `privateKey = KeyChain.getPrivateKey(this@LoginClaveActivity, alias)
                                certificateChain = KeyChain.getCertificateChain(this@LoginClaveActivity, alias)`

Comment: Supongo que antes de llamar a esta función le has pedido al usuario el permiso necesario para acceder a ella, ¿no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya encontré el error, el problema era aqui: `this@LoginClaveActivity`. Para ser mas concretos la solución que encontré fue pasarle `applicationContext` en vez de la actividad y se solucionó perfectamente.